# Android Studio - Robolectric: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: no such label com.my.app:string/app_name

Tags: android, android-studio, robolectric

This issue I cannot seem to get rid of, I've gone through probably 3 or 4 dozen articles and threads trying to resolve it. I've outlined everything below.

Basically the question is, is the issue I'm having a flaw with Robolectric? Or is there some small step I’m missing, or I have a weird combination of plugins.  Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Windows 7
Versions:

- Gradle            2.7
- Android Studio       1.3.2
- Robolectric      3.0
- Roboguice        3.+

Project Dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    classpath "com.newrelic.agent.android:agent-gradle-plugin:4.244.0"
    classpath 'com.github.triplet.gradle:play-publisher:1.1.2'
    classpath 'org.moallemi.gradle.advanced-build-version:gradle-plugin:1.5.0'
}
```

App Dependencies

```
import org.moallemi.gradle.internal.VersionCodeType

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'newrelic'
apply plugin: 'com.github.triplet.play'
apply plugin: 'org.moallemi.advanced-build-version'

android {
def SERVICE_ACCOUNT = “account”;
def P12_KEY = file('mykey.p12')

signingConfigs {
    releaseConfig {
…
    }
}

compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

advancedVersioning {
    nameOptions {
        versionMajor 6
        versionMinor advancedVersioning.versionCode
    }
    codeOptions {
        versionCodeType VersionCodeType.AUTO_INCREMENT_ONE_STEP
    }
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.my.app ="
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode = advancedVersioning.versionCode
    versionName = advancedVersioning.versionName
}

buildTypes {
    def STRING = "String"
    def URL = "URL"
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseConfig
    }
    staging {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    development {
        minifyEnabled false
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
    }
}
testOptions {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.+'

    compile(name: 'library-release', ext: 'aar')

    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:3.+'
    provided 'org.roboguice:roboblender:3.+'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0"
}

repositories {
flatDir {
    dirs 'libs'
}
}
```

Custom Gradle Runner

```
public class M1stRoboelectricGradleTestRunner extends RobolectricTestRunner {
public M1stRoboelectricGradleTestRunner(Class<?> testClass) throws InitializationError {
    super(testClass);
    String buildVariant = (BuildConfig.FLAVOR.isEmpty()
            ? "" : BuildConfig.FLAVOR+ "/") + BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE;
    String intermediatesPath = BuildConfig.class.getResource("")
            .toString().replace("file:", "");
    intermediatesPath = intermediatesPath
            .substring(0, intermediatesPath.indexOf("/classes"));

    System.setProperty("android.package",
            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
    System.setProperty("android.manifest",
            intermediatesPath + "/manifests/full/"
                    + buildVariant + "/AndroidManifest.xml");
    System.setProperty("android.resources",
            intermediatesPath + "/res/merged/" + buildVariant);
    System.setProperty("android.assets",
            intermediatesPath + "/assets/" + buildVariant);
}

@Override protected AndroidManifest getAppManifest(Config config) {

    String manifestProperty = System.getProperty("android.manifest");
    String resProperty = System.getProperty("android.resources");
    String assetsProperty = System.getProperty("android.assets");
    AndroidManifest manifest = new AndroidManifest(Fs.fileFromPath(manifestProperty), Fs.fileFromPath(resProperty),
            Fs.fileFromPath(assetsProperty)){
    };
    manifest.setPackageName("com.my.app");
    return manifest;
}
}
```

Test Class

```
@RunWith(M1stRoboelectricGradleTestRunner.class)
public class MainActivityTest {
    private MainActivity mActivity;
    private Button mButton;
    private TextView mTextView;

@Before
public void setup() {

    mActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(
            MainActivity.class).create().get();
    mButton = (Button) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.signInButton);
    mTextView = (TextView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.linkContact);
}
```

Issue:
The following line of code is what is throwing the error:

```
 mActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(
    MainActivity.class).create().get();
```

Initially, I attempted to use the default robolectricGradleTestRunner but kept receiving the ResourceNotFound com.my.app::string/app_name not found. After perusing a ridiculous amount of articles and blogs, I came across [this](http://nenick-android.blogspot.com/2015/03/android-studio-110-and-robolectric-30.html) and was able to get past it by implementing a custom runner. This solved the app_name issue, sort of.

1. If on the test class I put @config(sdk = 21) I receive the error I
   was receiving initially:

   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: no such label com.my.app:string/app_name
   at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.getActivityTitle(ActivityController.java:104)
   at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.attach(ActivityController.java:49)
   at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController$1.run(ActivityController.java:121)
   at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:304)
   at org.robolectric.shadows.CoreShadowsAdapter$2.runPaused(CoreShadowsAdapter.java:45)
   at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:118)
   at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:129)
   at org.members1st.mobile.MainActivityTest.setup(MainActivityTest.java:32)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
   at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
   at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
   at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
   at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:251)
   at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:188)
   at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:54)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
   at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:152)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
   at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
   at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
   at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
   at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
2. If I leave the SDK alone, I get Robolectric doesn’t support API 22

So far I’ve tried:

1. Creating a custom BuildConfig and passing that in per
   recommendations on [this](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1623) robolectric thread.
2. Setting the packageName in the @config per recommendations on [this thread](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1954).
3. Overloading the new ApplicationManifest to send back the api level
4. Setting the targetSdk to 21 in my Gradle file
5. Pretty much every combination of the previous steps results in the same error.
6. Verified that the app_name is in the values.xml resources file generated by the test build
7. I’ve tried using

   mActivity = Robolectric.setupActivity(MainActivity.class);

Instead of

```
mActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(
    MainActivity.class).create().get();
```

8. Regular unit tests are working when being run.

Comment: Tip: try formatting your question properly and move the actual question to the top.

Comment: Awesome tip - any advice on what would be a better way to phrase it?

Comment: Is it editing mistake or your  `build.gradle` really have `applicationId "com.my.app ="`?

Comment: That's just a mistake, sorry. I had to sanitize the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the resolution to this was a face-palm for me but hopefully will help someone else.

The packageName is **NOT** the same as the applicationId. In most examples they are identical, so I didn't catch the difference, until I decided what the heck lets try it.

In the above, the package name was actually org.my.app BUT my applicationId was com.my.app

Once it was switched everything worked beautifully. Such a rookie mistake!

Comment: packageName is the same as applicationId in build.gradle

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk=21, packageName="com.my.app")
public class MainActivityTest
```

Comment: Yep - I had tried that turned out I made a simple stupid mistake. The packageName is not the applicationId, though in all examples I'd seen they were the same so I thought nothing of it - made the change as part of a last ditch effort and it worked. Super stupid mistake on my part.

Comment: What is the purpose of **sdk=21**?

Comment: To tell Robolectric to run the test against the Android sdk 21 else it will use the targetSdkVersion defined in the gradle file. Robolectric 3.0 does not support sdk 22.